# How to replace ai with human midgame? (multiplayer)

Tags: civilization-5

I'm running a pitboss sever and we're a quarter of the way through the game, doing a few turns a day. I have another friend who wants to play. Is there a way for the person to take over one of the AI Civs so we don't have to start a new game?

Comment: I would say save the game, then try reloading the game with him/her in-place of a computer. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 4):

If you select the **Internet** option when playing a game - you can in fact have a player take over an AI - and have an AI take over a human player.

To do this, you'll need a saved game when playing a previous **multiplayer** game (you can play single player on muliplayer mode). Then, host another game, load the saved game, and mark the AI you want a human to replace as **open**, and any human players you want switched to AI as **AI**. Start the game up, and voila!